# CORS: Preflight works but the main request fails

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have setup C# WebApi 2.2 with OWIN.Cors setup like below:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
            | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
```

And also have following setup in the `Web.config`

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Now, the Preflight request from Angular works perfectly, sample below:

```
**Response Headers**
    access-control-allow-credentials: true
    access-control-allow-headers: authorization
    access-control-allow-origin: https://localhost:4200
    access-control-expose-headers: Request-Context
    content-length: 0
    date: Sun, 30 May 2021 05:10:41 GMT
    request-context: appId=cid-v1:04c910be-c0d6-4c56-b923-d591b73940c1
    server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
    x-powered-by: ASP.NET
    x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?RTpcRHJvcGJveFxTbWFydFRhc2tcQmFja2VuZFxTbWFydFRhc2suQ29yZVxTbWFydFRhc2suV2ViQXBpXEdlbmVyYWxcQXBwU2l0ZVNldHRpbmdzXGRldg==?=

**Request Headers**
    :authority: localhost:44366
    :method: OPTIONS
    :path: /General/AppSiteSettings/dev
    :scheme: https
    accept: */*
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: en,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
    access-control-request-headers: authorization
    access-control-request-method: GET
    origin: https://localhost:4200
    referer: https://localhost:4200/
    sec-fetch-dest: empty
    sec-fetch-mode: cors
    sec-fetch-site: same-site
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36
```

But the Get request fails with the error (Do note, the endpoint in WebApi controller is not even hit):

Error in Console logs:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://localhost:44366/General/AppSiteSettings/dev?hostname=localhost'
> from origin 'https://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Error in Chrome Network Tab

> Cross Origin Resource sharing error: MissingAllowOriginHeader

On inspecting the failed request. This is what I find:

```
**Response Headers:**
    access-control-expose-headers: Request-Context
    cache-control: private
    content-length: 40070
    content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    date: Sun, 30 May 2021 05:10:43 GMT
    request-context: appId=cid-v1:04c910be-c0d6-4c56-b923-d591b73940c1
    server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
    x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
    x-powered-by: ASP.NET
    x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?RTpcRHJvcGJveFxTbWFydFRhc2tcQmFja2VuZFxTbWFydFRhc2suQ29yZVxTbWFydFRhc2suV2ViQXBpXEdlbmVyYWxcQXBwU2l0ZVNldHRpbmdzXGRldg==?=

**Request Headers:**
    :authority: localhost:44366
    :method: GET
    :path: /General/AppSiteSettings/dev
    :scheme: https
    accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: en,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
    authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjY....
    cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1.....
    origin: https://localhost:4200
    referer: https://localhost:4200/
    sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    sec-fetch-dest: empty
    sec-fetch-mode: cors
    sec-fetch-site: same-site
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36
```

I wanted to confirm if my settings are working fine, hence I removed the Web.config part and now the response too fails, sample below:

```
**Response Headers**
    allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
    content-length: 0
    date: Sun, 30 May 2021 05:00:39 GMT
    public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
    server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
    x-powered-by: ASP.NET
    x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?RTpcRHJvcGJveFxTbWFydFRhc2tcQmFja2VuZFxTbWFydFRhc2suQ29yZVxTbWFydFRhc2suV2ViQXBpXEdlbmVyYWxcQXBwU2l0ZVNldHRpbmdzXGRldg==?=
**Request Headers:**
    :authority: localhost:44366
    :method: OPTIONS
    :path: /General/AppSiteSettings/dev
    :scheme: https
    accept: */*
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: en,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
    access-control-request-headers: authorization
    access-control-request-method: GET
    origin: https://localhost:4200
    referer: https://localhost:4200/
    sec-fetch-dest: empty
    sec-fetch-mode: cors
    sec-fetch-site: same-site
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36
```

As a conclusion I think CORs is atleast working for `OPTIONS` request perfectly fine, but the main requests are failing. The interesting part is that GET Request is not even hitting the endpoint in the controller.

Do let me know if you have any ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Whats the status of response on the get? Is it 200 or 500

Comment: The call itself is not being made I guess from the frontend I guess, in the status column in Chrome it shows "Cors Error" with no status code.

Comment: You should still have some sort of status code somewhere maybe in the console. If the answer below doesn't work please add the console errors to the question

Comment: Added the console log too